# Finding $\cos(a)$, given $\sin (a+b) = x$ and $\sin (a-b) = y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Given equation:
> $$\sin (a+b) = x$$
> $$\sin (a-b) = y$$
> Find $\cos(a)$.

I tried to expand $\sin(a+b)$, but still don't get the answer. Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:
$$x = \sin(a+b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) + \cos(a) \sin(b)$$
$$y = \sin(a-b) = \sin(a) \cos(b) - \cos(a) \sin(b)$$

$$x-y = 2\cos(a) \sin(b) \Longrightarrow \frac{x-y}{2 \sin(b)} = \cos(a).$$

I don't know how to deal with $\sin(b)$.

Comment: Have you seen the answers? It seems like you edited your post to include your thoughts without reading the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shall find $\cos 2a$, then find $\cos a$ from there.

$$\begin{align}
\cos 2a
&=\cos((a+b)+(a-b)) \\
&=\cos(a+b)\cos(a-b)-\sin(a+b)\sin(a-b) \\
&=\pm\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-y^2)}-xy \\
&=\pm\sqrt{(x^2-1)(y^2-1)}-xy
\end{align}$$

Since $\cos2a=2\cos^2 a-1$, we know that $\cos^2a=\dfrac{\cos2a+1}{2}$.

$$
\implies\cos^2a=\frac{\pm\sqrt{(x^2-1)(y^2-1)}-xy+1}{2} \\
\begin{align}
\implies\cos a
&=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\pm\sqrt{(x^2-1)(y^2-1)}-xy+1}{2}} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: How do you avoid $\pm$ signs on each $\sqrt{\cdot}$?

Comment: Oops, I forgot. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thanks. The final result's two $\pm$ signs are of course independent.

Comment: Since $0\le x,y\le 1$ I'm quite surprised you explicitly switched from positive quantities $1-x^2$ to negative ones $x^2-1$ under the radicals ?!

Comment: Well it looks better to me. It doesn't matter really.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Expand $\sin (a+b)$ and $\sin (a-b)$ and subtract one from the other.  You should get something in terms of $\cos a$ and another term.  Then isolate the $\cos a$ term (it might require rearranging some terms).

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Usually when I put down "Hint," I don't want to give the complete answer away because it attracts downvotes or "don't give the answer" comments.  It looks like the OP got the hint.